# Assembly data types and storage space

Tags: assembly, types

How is it possible to store multiple characters of word in a Byte data type? I mean if the size of a variable declared as a Byte have the storage space of 1 Byte then how is it possible to assign more than 1 Byte? Look below:

```
     section .data
msg  db 'hello world'   ;here msg is defined to be byte but holds 11 char's
```

If I am misunderstanding, Please help?

Comment: msg just points to the first byte in the 11-byte series

Comment: Thanks but why then do we need the word, double word,.., definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DB psuedo op really should be read as, "Define Byte(s)".

It accepts a series of expressions, and string literals.  For each expression, it assigns one byte of memory, filled with the value of that expression as computed at assembly time.  String literals are treated as a series of bytes, and each character of the string literal is assigned one byte of memory.   So:

LABEL DB  17, "ABC", 2

fills in memory bytes, in order:

```
  0x11
  0x41
  0x42
  0x43
  0x02
```

The label on the DB command gets an assembly time value of the location of the first byte filled by the DB.

Other pseudo ops, like DW ("Define Word(s)"), DD ("Define DoubleWord(s)"), and DQ ("Define Quadword(s)"), spelling may depend on your assembler, accepts series of expressions, and fills "word" (2 bytes/16 bits), "doublewords (4 bytes/32 bits) and "quadwords" (8 bytes/64 bit) value in the assembled output.  These ops typically do not accept strings (e.g., a quadword series of memory locations containing individual characters simply isn't used very much).